# Using jQuery isotope to constantly rotate through the elements in order of sort

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-isotope

I am wondering if there is a way to keep rotating through elements in isotope. [Moving the first element to the last position with animation and repeating this process constantly] Something akin to an organized shuffle.

**Here is a fiddle with isotope and the necessary default filter set up: http://jsfiddle.net/boriskourt/Czavf/1/**

[Note, new elements can be added or old elements can be removed at any time]

I am using masonry horizontal, and everything will only ever be on one line.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is - when would the elements "rotate"? On a click event of a button somewhere? On a click event of an Isotope element? On some other type of event? You could put the elements in an array and shift that on each event.

Comment: I would like it to rotate constantly, something akin to set interval.

Comment: Well, is that thing - with all elements horizontal - not simply an automatically running jQuery slideshow/carousel?

Comment: I need the sorting and filtering aspects of isotope for other purposes. Placing new elements in the right positions as well as keeping everything order dynamically. All of that logic is already coded, I was just asked to have  them rotate as well instead of only move when something changes.

Comment: So, what you want is to replace Isotope's CSS transitions with another kind. That's over my head. Maybe you should also browse Isotope's github issues and answers.

Comment: Ill take a look at their github issues. And no its not replacing animations, if you have a moment take a look at their shuffle demo: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/elements-partial.html [there is a shuffle button in the last row]

It lets you shuffle the contents randomly, all I want is a similar method that just moves the first to the end repeatedly.

Comment: I've used Isotope on various sites, but never dared to actually go into "jquery.isotope.js" and tweak its functionality...